# How to make watchOS use dark variant of color?

Tags: swiftui, watchos

I have "Any Appearance" and "Dark" variants set for all my colors. However, the watchOS insists on using the "Any Appearance" instead of the "Dark" color which would make more sense since the watch is only dark mode.

I tried adding `.preferredColorScheme(.dark)` modifier in my SwiftUI, and also tried adding "Appearance" = "Dark" in my info.plist, but it insists on using the "Any Appearance" color.

How do I tell watchOS to use the dark mode variances of colors?

Comment: Have you tried it with the color scheme environment key?

Comment: Something like:

Text("Hello, World!")
            .foregroundColor(Color.blue.dark)
            .environment(\.colorScheme, .dark)

Comment: Apple Watch doesn't have dark mode or light mode for that matter ir can't tell the difference the colors should not have variants.

Comment: @MuhammadUmair I tried `.environment(\.colorScheme, .dark)` and `.colorScheme(.dark)` but still no :(

@loremipsum I have themes shared across iOS, macOS, tvOS, and watchOS. I don't want to duplicate themes but instead force watch to look at the dark variant which I think is not only reasonable but should be automatic.